# dhtmlxlyout header text align center

Tags: layout, alignment, dhtmlx

Then dhtmlxLayout cell is collapsed, how can I make the header text as center align and how to make the entire tab cell as clickable when it is in collapsed state?
I have the next code:

```
dhxLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, "3U");
dhxLayout.cells('a').setText('<div id="a">Text to Center</div>');
dhxLayout.cells('b').setText('<div id="b">Text to Center</div>');
dhxLayout.attachEvent("onDblClick", function (itemId){
    //how can I do it here?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the next approach:

```
var h, panName;
function doOnLoad() {
    dhxLayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, "3U");
    //put cell text in a div
    dhxLayout.cells('a').setText('<div id="a">Text to Center</div>');
    dhxLayout.cells('b').setText('<div id="b">Text to Center</div>');
    //use double click to collapse/expand cell
    dhxLayout.attachEvent("onDblClick", function (itemId){
        if (dhxLayout.cells(itemId).isCollapsed() == false){
            dhxLayout.cells(itemId).collapse();
        }
        else dhxLayout.cells(itemId).expand();
    });
    //center the label
    dhxLayout.attachEvent("onCollapse", function(name){
        panName = name;
        recount(panName)
    });
    dhxLayout.attachEvent("onPanelResizeFinish", function(){
        recount(panName)
    });
    dhxLayout.attachEvent("onResizeFinish", function(){
        recount(panName)
    });
}
function recount(panName){
    h = dhxLayout.cells("a").getHeight();
    document.getElementById(panName).style.width = (h-20)+"px";
    document.getElementById(panName).style.textAlign = 'center';
}
```